# PHP Retrieve information from five different tables with correct order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I develop a chat system where students and staff can exchange different messages. I have developed a database where we have five tables: the staff table, the student, the message and two mapping tables the staff_message and stu_message. These tables contain only the student/staff id and the message id.

My problem is that I cannot order the messages. I mean that I cannot figure out how can I make one SQL statement that will return all messages and be ordered by for example the ID. The code that I have made is this:

```
$qu = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stu_message");
while($row7 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qu)){
    $que = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentid =".$row7['stu_id']);

    while($row8 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($que)) {
        $username = $row8['username'];
    }

    $query3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM message WHERE id=".$row7['mid']);
    while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3)) {
        echo $row6['date']."<strong> ".$username."</strong> ".$row6['text']."<br>";             
    }   
}

$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM staff_message");    
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id =".$row3['staff_id']);

    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $username = $row5['username'];
    }

    $query3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM message WHERE id=".$row3['m_id']);
    while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3)) {
        echo $row6['date']."<strong> ".$username."</strong> ".$row6['text']."<br>";             
    }   
}
?>
```

The result is different from that I want. To be more specific first are shown the messages from the students and then from the staff. My question is, is there any query that it can combine basically all these four tables in one and all messages will be shown in correct order? for example by the id? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: One thought on the design why have 2 tables for staff and students?  You can create one table to hold them and then a flag in that table to identify them as staff and students.  Then you would just need one table for that, and one table for messages.  Then you could track back to find what messages were from student/staff by that flag.  Then that would solve your issue as well and be better overall DB design.

Comment: Why are you using `while` loops to get the usernames? There can only be one student or staff with a particular ID, right?

Comment: Looks like you actually have **five** tables, not just four.

Comment: @Brad First of all thank you for your answer,   I can understand yout point of view but in the future the staff will make different things from the student. For example the staff can insert a new student, or may can upload a text where each staff id will be associated with a text. I don't know if is it correct to have everything in one table, both students and staff and everything will be depending from the 'role' attribute.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `JOIN` to get the username corresponding to the `stu_id` or `staff_id`, and the text of the message, rather than separate queries.

Then use `UNION` to combine both queries into a single query, which you can then order with `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT u.id, u.text, u.username
FROM (
    SELECT s.username, m.text, m.id
    FROM message AS m
    JOIN stu_message AS sm ON m.id = sm.mid
    JOIN student AS s ON s.id = sm.stu_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.username, m.text, m.id
    FROM message AS m
    JOIN staff_message AS sm ON m.id = sm.m_id
    JOIN staff AS s ON s.id = sm.staff_id
) AS u
ORDER BY u.id
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't want to be annoying but the 'u.id', 'u.id' or 'u.message' are the attributes from the message table? If yes then I have to delete the u.username since there is no any attribute with than name in this table. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `u` is the alias for the subquery with the `UNION`. The first query in the union gets `username` from the `student` table, the second query gets it from the `staff` table. Don't you see `s.username` in both queries?

Comment: Barmar I want to thank you about your answer! Now I got it!